# How are morals epistemically any different from any other desire?

Tags: ethics

How is "I don't like to hit people" any different from "I don't like to eat chocolate?" Both are desires. Certain desires may be more universal than others but why is this relevant? How can there be a deeper justification for any desire apart from the fact that we feel them? Every desire comes about by some sort of want/intuition which in turn can be influenced by genetics and environmental causes.

As such, the whole notion of moral philosophy seems like an unneeded waste of time. If it's similar to any other desire, it is no more useful developing moral philosophies than it is to develop a philosophy about different kinds of positions about whether we like chocolate, or any kind of item that ultimately gives us pleasure or pain.

It seems that any and all moral philosophies amount to "Why I like X and why I dislike Y". But this could be done for any X you like/dislike yet developing entire books on philosophies about other desires seem fruitless. So why is it considered fruitful in the case of morality?

Comment: Intuitionist morals is but one moral theory (and probably a rather minor in academics). Stating that morals are reducible to feelings of dislike/disgust is a premise that needs justification. The fact that we do have a special brain structure for intervening in (inhibiting) action when it is *considered* wrong (as opposed to *feeling* wrong) should make you question that premise. Problems in the fronto-parietal network moderating reactive response inhibition are the main reason for the 'socially inappropriate' behaviour of ADHD people despite better judgement.

Comment: If there is no mind independent way of showing that X is wrong, then that implies it must be generated from the brain. All that what you wrote would show, if even true, since I cannot verify that without doing extensive research, is that certain intuitions/feelings are determined more fundamentally by the brain. But the brain causes any and all desires and feelings and intuitions. So why does this one deserve hundreds of books of philosophies around the subject?

Comment: The problem is that your framing suggests that feelings are *the only* moral thing that the brain produces and that it was a unitary body. Both are evidently false. The brain does many things we don't understand the slightest still and has many parts reinforcing and inhibiting each other at any time. Thus, making differences where there *are* differences is important. A major part of what philosophy does as a method is getting hold of and framing important differences. That certainly goes beyond reasonable limits at times but this still doesn't make painting with a brush too broad more useful.

Comment: How do I make the assumption that feelings are the only thing that the brain produces? The question was moreso why intuitions about what we desire with regards to food or sex or whatever else hold any less epistemic weight than moral intuitions?

Comment: You state "morals" and make assumptions about "moral philosophy" as a whole. If you just asked how, given they exist, moral intuitions should have an epistemic status different from other feelings and desires, fine. But that is not what you did.

Comment: "I don't like to hit people" is not an ethics rule.

Comment: "*Your right to freely swing your arm stops at the end of my nose.*"

Answer (score 1):

One would be hard pressed to say that one had a clear, concrete feeling such as, "I like it when people act on universalizable maxims," or, "I like it when people promote the greatest aggregate goodness," or, "I like it when people harmonize the metaphorical cities of their souls." Or even, "I like it when people obey the written commands of omnipotent beings."

However, a deeper issue is that sometimes feelings for actions that conform to those kinds of principles can be inculcated *by* the more vaguely emotional grounds someone might have for adopting those principles. True, sometimes a Kantian might prefer certain specific courses of action, a utilitarian some other, and then they'll trace their motivation backwards to the relevant supporting theory. Slippery-slope fallacies are infamously prevalent in moral reasoning. Still, with respect to Kant proper, for instance, how would we interpret his assertion that some moral rules are analytic, yet others are synthetic? He used, "Act according to the truth" (i.e. don't perform actions such that, by their performance, you have a culpably false representation in mind) as an example of an analytic command. Did he just "like it" when people didn't act on false premises? Why then go through the trouble of claiming that the categorical imperative was synthetic?

It's kind of like one of the problems with egoism: if egoism were so deeply ingrained in us, why would we try to prove that it's false? In other words, the array of moral concepts is more complicated than reports of what one likes or dislikes: one can ask what the difference between being permitted and being obligated is, how there might be different senses of permissions, etc. If [Alessio Moretti](https://www.facebook.com/alessio.moretti.94) is right, for example, then the deontic concepts we usually make use of are theoretically embedded in an *n*-dimensional pseudofractal manifold each of whose nodes encodes for concepts akin to, but far beyond, mere permission and obligation. So suppose you were on the 19th level of the pseudofractal and denoted some arbitrary higher such operator "hypererogation." If you said, "It is hypererogatory that I eat pineapple pizza with chopsticks made of uranium," are you saying just that you like eating pineapple pizza in that way?

You might compare/contrast [deontic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/) with [preference logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/preferences/#PreLog), then, to get at whether and how ethical concepts really are plausibly reducible to approval concepts.

Comment: Why make everything so complicated? Couldn't we just take "*Do what works best overall*" as a maxim? Cooperation works best, the research has been done.

Comment: @ScottRowe, because reality doesn't work that way. No one's "making" moral questions this complex, they just *are* that complex, and if some vague principle of cooperation had really been confirmed by "the research," it would answer all those questions. Does it?

Comment: It answers them for me. I think the real problem is that people don't *want to* cooperate. If they cooperated, they would figure out what works.

Comment: @ScottRowe, what do you mean by "works"? How does figuring out whether there are multiple permission operators in deontic logic relate to a theory of cooperation? What is the definition of cooperation at issue?

Comment: Cooperation: helping rather than hindering. We don't need to worry about duty, we need to look at results.

Comment: @ScottRowe, you're using the word "need" in a deontic way, though. And helping who? With what? If someone's goal is to kill 100,000 people, and I have a nuclear weapon, wouldn't I be helping them if I gave them the weapon?

Comment: Ok. It would be best for humans overall if they worked together to fulfill necessities and increase enjoyment, for everyone. There really is no "I" in "Team", so all this individual harming has to go.